# How to make the kube-scheduler place pods on less busy nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

In my cluster, I have over 20 different nodes, and the first 3 nodes are constantly at 90%+ pod capacity, whereas the remaining nodes are at ~10% pod capacity. Is there a way to configure deployments to schedule pods to the least busy nodes? I also cannot just simply add a node selector to the least busy nodes either, as nodes can get deleted and new ones can get created regularly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could use pod antiAffinity in order to split across different nodes the pods that consumes the most. Even if they belongs to the same deployment, you could use its own app label to separate each pod.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#more-practical-use-cases

Also something you can try is creating more than one nodegroup on the same cluster so its easiest to isolate critical services on certain nodes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> [kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/kube-scheduler/) is the default scheduler for Kubernetes and runs
> as part of the control plane. kube-scheduler is designed so that, if
> you want and need to, you can write your own scheduling component and
> use that instead.
>
> Kube-scheduler selects an optimal node to run newly created or not yet
> scheduled (unscheduled) pods. Since containers in pods - and pods
> themselves - can have different requirements, the scheduler filters
> out any nodes that don't meet a Pod's specific scheduling needs.
>
> In a cluster, Nodes that meet the scheduling requirements for a Pod
> are called feasible nodes. If none of the nodes are suitable, the pod
> remains unscheduled until the scheduler is able to place it.
>
> The scheduler finds feasible Nodes for a Pod and then runs a set of
> functions to score the feasible Nodes and picks a Node with the
> highest score among the feasible ones to run the Pod. The scheduler
> then notifies the API server about this decision in a process called
> binding.

You can use [topology spread constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/) to control how Pods are spread across your cluster among failure-domains such as regions, zones, nodes, and other user-defined topology domains. This can help to achieve high availability as well as efficient resource utilization.